# Problema Tentar realizar consulta Aplicação c# + Banco

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

Estou fazendo uma lista de clientes, porém esta retornando este erro:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'Cpf_Cpnj' does not belong to table .'

Esta coluna, `Cpf_Cnpj`, consta no meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo solucionar esse problema...

Código da classe `model`:

```
using DnxVendas.Uteis;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace DnxVendas.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public string ClienteId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Cpf_Cnpj { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Senha { get; set; }

        public List<Cliente> ListarTodosClientes()
        {
            List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();
            Cliente item;
            DAL objDAL = new DAL();
            string sql = "Select ClienteId, Nome, Cpf_Cnpj, Email, Senha From Cadastro.Clientes order by Nome asc";
            DataTable dt = objDAL.RetDaaTable(sql);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                item = new Cliente
                {
                    ClienteId = dt.Rows[i]["ClienteId"].ToString(),
                    Nome = dt.Rows[i]["Nome"].ToString(),
                    Cpf_Cnpj = dt.Rows[i]["Cpf_Cpnj"].ToString(), // Problema ocorre nesta linha
                    Email = dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString(),
                    Senha = dt.Rows[i]["Senha"].ToString()

                };

                lista.Add(item);
            }

            return lista;
        }
    }
}
```

Já rodei a minha *string* que faz a consulta no banco de dados e retorna a informação correta:

```
string sql = "Select ClienteId, Nome, Cpf_Cnpj, Email, Senha From Cadastro.Clientes order by Nome asc";
```

Comment: Tornando explicito e-mails, CPFs e nomes de pessoas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cpf_Cpnj` deveria ser `Cpf_Cnpj` na seguinte linha:

```
                Cpf_Cnpj = dt.Rows[i]["Cpf_Cpnj"].ToString(), // Problema ocorre nesta linha
```

Comment: Nossa que falta te atenção rs, é isso mesmo obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

A exceção existe quando algum argumento não é válido

Na linha com o comentário:

> "- *Problema ocorre nesta linha*"

Você tenta extrair dados de uma coluna chamada `Cpf_Cpnj`, ao invés de `Cpf_Cnpj`.